# Confusing ticklabels with imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to show a heatmap of 2D data using imshow, and I'd like to update the ticklabels to reflect my data. But things are confusing when I use `get_x/yticklabels`:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
axes.imshow(np.random.rand(5,5), interpolation='none')
fig.canvas.draw() # or just draw()
[t.get_text() for t in axes.get_yticklabels()]
# >>> [u'0.0', u'0', u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'']
[t.get_text() for t in axes.get_xticklabels()]
# >>> [u'0', u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'5', u'6', u'7', u'']
```

Now to `set_xticklabels`, I need to give it the same length array as the labels, but you can see that there are these blank labels, so I'm not sure how to proceed with my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of editing the tick labels manually, try using the `extent` argument to `imshow`:

> **extent** : scalars (left, right, bottom, top), optional, default: None
>
> The location, in data-coordinates, of the lower-left and upper-right corners. If None, the image is positioned such that the pixel centers fall on zero-based (row, column) indices.
>
> ([Source](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow))

This should make it automatically calculate the ticks based on the size of your array and the upper and lower bounds on each axis.

Comment: it's unclear to me how to use the `extent` argument. I am using imshow because the ticklabels get positioned centered at the various points of the heat map. Playing around with the extent argument seems to mess this up. Furthermore, I actually would like to apply text labels to at least one axis (i.e. A, B, C, etc.)